# How to declare function in typeScript within class?

Tags: typescript

How does one declare function like this in typescript within class? What I am trying to achieve is to declare all members first, and then provide implementation of the function later. I want to be able to quickly scan class to see all members. This does not work for me.

class myClass {

```
this.myFunction = myFunction;


function myFunction(){
}
```

}

Comment: exactly how you have asked it. This code is valid typescript code :)

Comment: Did you even try to enter this in typescript? Seems like the shortest way to find out whether that works.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript. This means that you can write ES5 or ES6 code, it will be perfectly compiled by `tsc`.

In TypeScript, even if you do not use type checking, it is OK:

```
function myFunction () {
  // Your code...
}

var myFunction = function () {
  // Your code...
};

let myFunction = function () {
  // Your code...
};

const myFunction = () => {
  // Your code...
};

// etc.
```